# Load website in Iframe using curl

Tags: php, iframe, curl

I am new in Curl, how to load external website? I am using the following code:

```
 function Get_Domain_Contents($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);


        return $data;   
}
```

now I want to know that how load website in an `iframe`.

Comment: You don't need curl when using iframe, unless you want to create a kind of a proxy ...

Comment: Why would you want to use CURL to load into an IFRAME? Just put the IFRAME SRC as the page you want to load.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
file_get_contents('http://someurl.com');
```